# How do I add a method to an existing extended function in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I extend an existing object method in jQuery?

For instance, I'm using [jqBarGraph](http://workshop.rs/jqbargraph/). Now I want to add an `addGrid()` function to it. I was thinking I'd do it like so:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.jqBarGraph.addGrid = function(){
    var o = this;
    // do something with 'o'
    return o;
  }
})(jQuery);
```

...but when I call `$('#chart').jqBarGraph(options).addGrid();` -- I get the error:

**`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addGrid' of undefined`**

Comment: Ensure you add it after your call to the plugin and before your regular script

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're adding a property to the function, so you can really only access it as e.g.

```
$('#chart').jqBarGraph.addGrid();
```

which is not what you want. It seems like `jqBarGraph` does not return anything when called. You'd have to patch the function yourself like this:

```
(function(old) {
  $.fn.jqBarGraph = function() {
    old.apply(this, arguments);  // call the actual function

    // return something
    return {
      addGraph: function() { ... }
    };
  };

  $.fn.jqBarGraph.defaults = old.defaults;  // restore properties
})($.fn.jqBarGraph);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll hop on GitHub as well to report to the developer that he should probably return a "this" with his function.

Comment: @Volomike: Yes, that seems reasonable. It wouldn't change the solution here, though.

Comment: I implemented this code -- worked awesome! The only thing to note is that "this" inside the addGraph() function is a different "this". Instead, one needs to do a `var oThis = this;` before the `old.apply()` statement, and then reference oThis inside the addGraph() function.